# Create Javascript program runnable in USB key

Tags: javascript, mobile, usb, device-driver

I would like to have your advice for making a new project.

The idea so simple.

Today, i have an existing Javascript library, which is able to connect to my server for retrieving information and to print this information in a simple web page.

I would like to try to make the same thing on an usb key :

- User connects his USB key (Wifi) on a TV ;
- Javascript program on usb key automatically launches a web page, fetch informations from server and show it into a web page on the TV

Is it possible to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible using a combination of autorun and for example node-js.

Comment: Do you have an example or an article about that ? Thanks

Comment: Information about autorun can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorun.inf You can start about any program using this technique if the security settings of the pc allow it. More information about nodejs can be found on their website: http://nodejs.org/